# Wordpress contact form 7 mail issues

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form

I am using contact form 7 and facing problem with this email while i am using 
ABC@gmail.com then i am receiving a mail, but  when I am going with this email
sanjay.yadav@polestarllp.com, I am not receiving any mail

sanjay.yadav@polestarllp.com
From
[your-name] 
Subject 
polestarllp "[your-subject]"

It's to difficult right now for me , can i left contact us form7 and use other or we have any solution .

Comment: have u check your spam folder?

Comment: I have checked and , also i have allow for low security apps

Comment: mail is going but not reciving

Comment: Can you please set [WP mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) setting after check.

Comment: The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
2016-05-24 08:14:33 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-05-24 08:14:35 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
2016-05-24 08:14:35 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: when i am using gmail.com  then every thing working fine

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set up the System with the WP mail SMTP Plugin which you can get from here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ and try to install it and then send a test message from your WordPress site to your mentioned Mail ID. If the Message is sent successfully it will send you the Mail to the particular Mail ID which you mention over there. Or it will guide you where is the Error.

Try to update the settings with the SMTP Credentials.

Comment: The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
2016-05-24 08:14:33 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-05-24 08:14:35 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
2016-05-24 08:14:35 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Send all WordPress emails via SMTP. is not working but php mail function is working

Comment: May be 'polestarllp.com' domain may not have SMTP configurations for sending emails from other server.

Comment: but when i am using sanjay.yadav@polestarllp.com then  message is  sending successfully on given id , but not reviving on  sanjay.yadav@polestarllp.com

Comment: Try this in the Mail Section part : from: [your-name]<*[your-email]*> and check it out.

Comment: you mean , i have to put the emai address under [your-email section]

Comment: In the Mail Tab under your created Contact Form you have to put <*[your-email]*> instead of <[your-email]> in From / Message body  and every place where you use email tag in Mail Tab which is the second Tab in CF7.

Comment: Could you paste the Screenshot where you have applied the change in CF7 as the email format.

Comment: chrome-extension://nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj/edit.html

Comment: Heh bro, How can i open it. provide me as link so that i can open up in Mozilla.

Comment: Change the Additional Header to : Reply-To: [your-name] <[your-email]>

Comment: friend i am not getting any mail after this

Comment: THANKS BRO , STEEL FACING PROBLEM

Comment: Hi Bro one more idea. You just run the simple PHP mail code by using a PHP file and check whether you receive mail to your ID and let me know.

Comment: how can i add this

Comment: You add the Normal .php file in the Server and inside the file you insert the PHP code for Sending Mail and test using IT. The To ID should be your Email ID and you just run the File from the browser.

Comment: Hi @SanjayYadav, Here is the Script : https://github.com/Nareshkumar979/PHP--Email/blob/master/index.php